# VBA Excel- Application or Object-Defined Error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

> Phase 1

I am attempting to search through the first column of every row in a range that has a value (formula, text, numbers, etc.) for a string. This string is generated by selecting from a drop down list. The selections are formatted like "Desktop, Dell, 790 - 4GB" and I am only concerned with the string of text before the 1st comma (AKA "Desktop" in this example.) I am using a Split() method in order to get the word before the first comma, and then attempting to use a Case statement to insert a string into another cell in the same row.

> Phase 2

I am using what is selected in the first drop down list to populate a second drop down list with pre-determined values.

> The Problem

The program is throwing Run-time error '1004': Application_defined or object-defined error. I don't know where to start.

> Original Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Whoops
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call splitter
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
If Not Target.HasFormula Then Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
End If
Whoops:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub splitter()
   Dim line() As String
   Dim rng, row As Range
   Dim lRow, lCol As Long
   lRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
   lCol = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
   Set rng = Cells(lRow, lCol)

   For Each row In rng.Rows
    If row.Value <> "" Then
        line = Split(Range(row, 1), ",")
        Select Case line(0)
           Case "Desktop"
               Range(row, 8).Value = "Desktop"
           Case "Laptop"
               Range(row, 8).Value = "Laptop"
           Case "Server"
               Range(row, 8).Value = "Server"
           Case Else
               Range(row, 8).Value = "N/A"
        End Select
    End If
   Next
End Sub
```

> Revised Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo Whoops
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call splitter
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
If Not Target.HasFormula Then Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
End If
Whoops:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub splitter()
   Dim line() As String
   Dim rng As Range, row As Range
   Dim lRow As Long
   lRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
   Set rng = Cells("A1:N" & lRow)

   For Each row In rng.Rows
    If row.Value <> "" Then
        line = Split(Cells(row, 1), ",")
        Select Case line(0)
           Case "Desktop"
               Cells(row, 8).Value = "Desktop"
           Case "Laptop"
               Cells(row, 8).Value = "Laptop"
           Case "Server"
               Cells(row, 8).Value = "Server"
           Case Else
               Cells(row, 8).Value = "N/A"
        End Select
    End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Three things 1) `Dim rng, row As Range` Change it to `Dim rng As Range, row As Range` else `rng` will be declared as a variant. Change for others as well 2) `Range(row, 8).Value` should be `cells(row, 8).Value` change for others as well 3) Also regarding `For Each row In rng.Rows`, `rng` is just 1 cell it will not have rows. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do... One moment...

Comment: Alright, I revised the code. See OP. now my error is: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Comment: Are all the dropdowns in Col B or Col A?... I am almost done with the changes to your code....

Comment: 1st dropdown is in Col A, 2nd dropdown will be in Col H (phase 2)

Comment: Ok 5 mins.. I am almost done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have combined your two codes into 1.

**PHASE 1**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)        
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue

        If Target.Value <> "" And InStr(1, Target.Value, ",") Then
            Select Case Split(Target.Value, ",")(0)
               Case "Desktop": Range("H" & Target.row).Value = "Desktop"
               Case "Laptop":  Range("H" & Target.row).Value = "Laptop"
               Case "Server":  Range("H" & Target.row).Value = "Server"
               Case Else:      Range("H" & Target.row).Value = "N/A"
            End Select
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue
        If Not Target.HasFormula Then Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: OK! This fixes my issue perfectly! There is only one issue. The code in the Worksheet_Change subroutine was for Uppercasing all text in Col B. With your code here, I have lost that functionality.

Comment: Beautifully done! Thank you so much! Now time to work on Phase 2.

Comment: For Phase two is this what you are trying? http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/

Comment: That is exactly what I need to do and will follow your tutorial and see if I can figure it out (for the sake of learning the material.) If I run into any problems, I will comment here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13820/discussion-between-jpm0004-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: @TimWillaims: Yes, I thought of that but Col 1 has DV list. However good point. I will update that as well.